# How can I host a isapi extension on windows azure

Tags: azure, isapi

I would like to deploy a web applicaction (ISAPI DLL 32 bit) on windows azure as hosted service.
Now, I have developed my isapi dll and works under IIS, and I would like how can I create a azure package and config file.

I need Visual Studio ? or can I create package using any tool ?

My Isapi dll have been created using delphi xe2.

Regards

Comment: Any luck here? http://int.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/29cdf931-4a86-4fa0-b2ae-c3081e8559c0

Comment: thank you but it is a insufficient information

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Visual Studio, you can use CSPack that is part of the Azure SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx

Comment: thank you for link, now I need to create files for MyIsapi.dll

Answer (score 0):

As Tom mentioned, you can use CSPack to create the package. As for the configuration file, you can either create it manually, or use the /generateConfigurationFile switch when using CSPack. This switch will automatically generate a skeleton of the cscfg file. If you don’t have anything to configure, you can just leave it as is. Please also refer to Tom’s link for more information about CSPack. Bottom line is you need a csdef file, which has to be created manually or using a Windows Azure development tool (such as Visual Studio). If you want to create it manually, I would like to suggest you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758711.aspx for its schema.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 0):

Also note please use a startup task to install the ISAPI filter. You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx for more information about startup task. Inside the startup task, you can run the Appcmd to install the ISAPI filter, or start a custom C# application, or use PowerShell. 
In addition, please check http://learningpcs.blogspot.com/2011/08/powershell-iis-7-adding-isapi-filters.html for the various options to install ISAPI filters.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.